# How to show multiple ids to a table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am making a Band application where a Venue has many Events and Bands through Events.

I realized that in my form for creating an event can only hold one band_id 
but I want to have many bands because it only makes sense to do so.

This is my Schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170817180728) do

  create_table "bands", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "genre"
    t.string "image"
    t.boolean "explicit_lyrics"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "date"
    t.boolean "alcohol_served"
    t.string "image"
    t.integer "venue_id"
    t.integer "band_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "venues", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "state"
    t.boolean "family_friendly"
    t.string "image"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

These are my models

```
class Venue < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :events
    has_many :bands, through: :events
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :venue
    belongs_to :band 
end

class Band < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :events
end
```

I am fairly new to rails this is a practice web app. I want to be able to be able to show multiple band_ids to my event.

Would I just keep repeating t.band_id in my form??

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to specify a foreign key relationship in your migration that reflects the Active Record associations you've set up in your models using `belongs_to` instead of a data type. This way, you'll get a references from one table to another, or in your case, from one table to two others, which is how one table with two one-to-many relationships is set up.

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :venues do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :city
      t.string :state
      t.boolean :family_friendly
      t.string :image
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :bands do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :genre
      t.string :image
      t.boolean :explicit_lyrics
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :events do |t|
      t.belongs_to :venue, index: true        # Look here!
      t.belongs_to :band, index: true         # and here!
      t.string :name
      t.text :date
      t.boolean :alcohol_served
      t.string :image
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: So how would link these actual relationships in my controller or shall I say when I build a form for the band, do I put t.venue with the venue id?

Comment: @dutchkillsg Why would you add venue information in a band view? Are bands only allowed to play in a single venue? Also, you seem now to be asking a second question about form building rather than migrations. Please limit questions to one per post. If you have a new question, ask it separately so this doesn't become a novel-length, personalized tutorial. If this answer answered your question, mark it accepted, then post your next question and we'll move on from there. If you do the work, we'll get you where you need to go.